# WMIC syntax to delete a printer Not Like

Tags: syntax, wmi, wmi-query, wmic

I need a wmic script to delete all printers where the `DeviceID` Not Like `'%%KM%%'`

The following syntax works to delete where like

```
printer where "DeviceID LIKE '%%KM%%'" delete
```

when I change to

```
printer where "DeviceID NOT LIKE '%%KM%%'" delete
```

I get
ERROR:

```
Description = Invalid query
```

How should I make this change?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
wmic printer where "deviceid like '%<Name>%'" delete
```

**Updated**

```
wmic printer where "NOT deviceid like '%<Name>%'" delete
```

Comment: yes,  I have this working.  I need to know how to change it to delete printers NOT LIKE '%<Name>%'"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Did this work for you? Considering marking it as an answer, so that it can help others.